# Executing collection of Expressions

Tags: c#

I have this

```
   List<Expression> levl1expressions;
```

Collection contains binary expressions like Expression.NotEqual, Expression.Equal
etc

I have another collection which is And and Or Conditions

```
List<Expression> levl2expressions;
```

I would like to execute these two expression collections

```
levl1expressions[0]+levl2expressions[0]+levl1expressions[1]+levl2expressions[1]....
```

Is this possible?

eg:

```
object.Name = "something" && object.Category != "myCategory"(//I transformed the string to expressions)

levl1expressions[0] = Expression.Equal(
               Expression.Property(Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyObject), "m")), 
               Expression.Constant("something")
levl1expressions[1] = Expression.NotEqual(....)

levl2expressions[0]= Expression.And(/*Would like to join levl1expressions*/)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? You may combine these expressions. But what result do you expect from `+`.

Comment: And as far as I know expressions, to _execute_ them you would need to combine them in a lambda expression, compile that and then you can invoke the resulting delegate. But we would need to know the parameters for this delegate or are there already constant expressions in these prepared expressions?

Comment: Edited the post

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you should not use lists at all. Instead you can create a single expression which will look like that:

```
var finalExpression = Expression.And(Expression.Equal(...), Expression.NotEqual(...));
```

If you would like to combine more logical operators then you can use a result of `Expression.And` as the right operand:

```
var finalExpression = Expression.And(Expression.Equal(...), Expression.And(Expression.NotEqual(...), Expression.Equal(...)));
```

To invoke the expression you need to compile first:

```
var action = Expression.Lambda<Action<bool>>(finalExpression).Compile();
```

Here `Action<bool>` is specifying what kind of function you create. `Action<bool>` basically means a function which is returning a boolean and has no parameters. Once you have that you can simply call it:

```
var result = action();
```

Bear in mind that expression compilation process is very expensive. Cache the result if you can.

Comment: the expression can be anything.I don't know what it will be in advance. I transform a string to expressions (object.Name = "something" && object.Category != "myCategory")

Comment: Well, no one said it will be easy. :) If you implement parser on your own then you still do not need a list. Instead you probably should use `Stack<Expression>`. Once you have that you could pop elements one by one, each time using `Expression.{And|Or}`, e.g. 


 `var final = Expression.And(stack.Pop(), stack.Pop()); final = Expression.And(stack.Pop(), final)`. First line would initialize an expression and then there should be an iteration over stack.

Comment: The filter wont change and I need to use this multiple times. I have to think of keeping the compiled expressions anyway.